# Need to make a really small post request and save response to disk but when my app is terminated my code does not finish executing

Tags: ios, background, webrequest

I am not sure how to go about performing a background request like this. I don't need to download huge files or anything, I just need to send a small post request and write some data to a file when I get a response from the server. This is for a 'cloud save system' I am writing for my game. The save files are only a couple of dozen bytes, and the request is generally completed in a fraction of a second.

I was using dispatch async to perform the operation in the background when the application was send to the background, and this worked fine, but it seems like dispatch_async stops functioning if the application is terminated by the user.

My only other option seems to be the (much more complicated) NSURLSession stuff, which lets the operating system take care of the request, allowing the OS to 'pause' sessions and 'resume' them later. This seems good for big files but my tiny post request does not need all this. I just want to send a small packet up to my server and wait for a response.

What are my options?

My code:

'DoSave' is supposed to send a post request to the server, but I am just download a 5mb test file as a test instead, since the operation takes long enough for me experiment with the app.

```
-(NSURLSession*)getSession{
    if(self.session == nil)
    {
        self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"PPCloudSave"] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    }

    return self.session;

}

-(void)DoSave{

    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/5meg.test3"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL];
    self.finderTask = [[self getSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [self.finderTask resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
 willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: NSURLSession is not complicated - what does your current code look like?

Comment: Do you mean when the user swipes up from the app switcher?  You can't run any code in this situation; your app is terminated

Comment: @paulw11, yes, how do I handle the situation where I want to upload the users save file when they minimize the application, but they happen to be on a slow connection so they 'swipe up from the app switcher' to kill the app before my work is complete?

Comment: Added code I have now

Comment: If the user swipes up there is nothing you can do.  I understand that this is a bad habit that many users have, but that's just the way it is

Comment: Isn't this the kind of scenario NSURLSession is designed for? I thought you basically tell it you want to send a certain web request, and it does that in the background, separate from your app?

So I should just keep using dispatch async ? I had that working, except ofcourse it failed to upload if the user swiped the app away.

Comment: You can try NSURLSession, but it is designed for handling transfers in the background. I am not sure what it's behaviour is if the user terminates your app. You would need to test it.